# Does UIOffsetMake() use the traditional top left corner origin (0,0) or bottom left origin?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7, uikit-dynamics

View geometry in UIKit specifies that it acts on an axis starting from the top left corner (0,0) and increasing in x and y as you travel toward the bottom right.

`UIOffsetMake()` is used a lot in UIKit Dynamics, and I was wondering if it follows a similar model. It's used to specify, relative to the center of the UIView, where you want the point where the view gets pushed to originate from.

If I specify `UIOriginMake(5.0, -5.0)` does it change it from the center to further in the bottom right? As in it goes down 5 vertically and 5 over horizontally? Or does it follow the traditional UIView model where that would indicate it goes 5 points over horizontally and 5 points up vertically?

I have no reason to think it doesn't follow UIView's model, but I wasn't positive and I wanted to make sure.

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result? Seems it would be quicker than posting a question and waiting for an answer.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't only ask for my own benefit, I ask in case others have a similar question and they'll be able to find the answer. Isn't that the point of StackOverflow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll find the answer in [the docs for the UIOffset struct](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_15):

> > The components are positive for right or down, negative for left or up.